# Identifying optimization-potential in weighted Hamilton cycles

Tags: heuristics, traveling-salesman-problem

From the (possibly incorrect) assumption that inoptimality of weighted Hamilton cycles, that resemble a heuristic solution to a TSP problem, can be identified by calculating the MST (minimum spanning tree) of "short" sequences of subsequent tour vertices, namely if these MSTs do not resemble a path graph, comes the

> **Question:**
>
> what is the algorithmic complexity of calculating the highest lower bound $k$ such that all MSTs of $h,\ \left(2\le h\le k\lt n\right)\ $consecutive vertices in a given weighted Hamilton cycle are path graphs?

**As a side-remark** it may be worth noting that constructing a line graph from a tree graph can accomplished by a sequence of exchanging single tree edges with a non-tree edge and doing so greedily, reducing the variance of tree-vertex degrees at minimal weight-increase, may provide a method for post optimizing heuristic solutions to TSP instances.